# Git.custom_environment not working for Repo.clone_from in docker

Tags: gitpython

I have problem with using `Git.custom_environment` and `Repo.clone_from` methods.
Running in a non-docker environment is successful and it fails to run under docker environment

```
gitpython version 3.1.9
python version 3.6.4
git version 2.24.3
```

mycode

```
Repo.clone_from(sourcecode, localpath, branch=branch, env=dict(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=git_ssh_cmd))
```

it's my fault or problem is the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on something similar to this.
As far as I know, in a docker environment your git settings aren't initialized.

Adding this snippet to the top of my dockerfile helped.

```
RUN git config --global user.name "user"
RUN git config --global user.email "user@email"
```

Also make sure that when you clone you specify the ssh option `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` if you are using ssh.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it :)